# Any integer wildcard in python?

Tags: python

I have a statement:

```
if self.rank == self.cube.Get_cart_rank([x, y, 0])
```

and I would like to use wildcard so it accepts any value as x and y. I was thinking of using (True, True, 0), but will it work for point [0,0,0]? Any advice how to do it?

Comment: What is `Get_cart_rank`?

Comment: MPI function, but it does not matter. The numbers in arguments will be in scope non-negative integers.

Comment: There is no integer that equals every other integer, and that's a good thing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'use wilcard' ?

Comment: Wildcard means that it has to be true for any integer given as parameter.

Comment: I would write an additional method for your `cube` class that allows you to retrieve the rank of the integer without having to access (x,y) values as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if there exist some values for `x` and `y` such that your `if` condition is `True`. You would have to search for such a pair explicitly:

```
found_pair = False
# MAX_X and MAX_Y would be have to be supplied by you
for x in range(0, MAX_X+1):
    for y in range(0, MAX_Y+1):
        if self.rank == self.cube.Get_cart_rank([x,y,0]):
            found_pair = True
            break

if found_pair:
    ...
```

There are languages (such as Prolog) which provide for ways to write code that ask such questions, then structure and perform the search for you. However, Python is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you, that`s what I was curious of - if you can avoid using for loops for that.

Comment: `if any(self.rank == self.cube.Get_cart_rank([x,y,0]) for x in range(MAX_X+1) for y in range(MAX_Y+1)): ... `

Comment: Good modification to avoid needing the temporary `found_pair` variable. I'm still stuck in a python-2.4 mindset, when `any` wasn't available.

Comment: Thats basically double for loop rewritten, but very useful answer nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I would use `None, None, 0` for wildcards and then in `Get_cart_rank` to check for wildcard `if x is None`. There's a better way of doing this by using default arguments, but I'd need more info.

Comment: If you want a more specific answer give us more details, what is `self.rank`, what does `Get_cart_rank` return, what are you comparing for etc.

Comment: Get_cart_rank is mpi4py method which returns rank of node in cartesian topology. What I want is for the statement to return true for nodes with coordinates of (x=any_int, y=any_int, z=0).